# Package pcl - Ubuntu 13.10 - Installation ROS Groovy from source

Tags: ros, pcl, source, package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to install Ros Groovy on Ubuntu 13.10. (Yes Groovy because the last project I used uses it)
I'm following this tutorial: wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source

But I'm stuck when I try to run this command:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install-space /opt/ROS/groovy/

make[2]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/common.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: ***
[common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/distances.cpp.o]
Error 1 make[2]: ***
[common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/io.cpp.o]
Error 1 make[2]: ***
[common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/intersections.cpp.o]
Error 1 make[1]: ***
[common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all]
Error 2 make[1]: *** Waiting for
unfinished jobs.... make[2]: ***
[octree/CMakeFiles/pcl_octree.dir/src/octree_impl.cpp.o]
Error 1 make[1]: ***
[octree/CMakeFiles/pcl_octree.dir/all]
Error 2 

Linking CXX shared library
../lib/libpcl_io_ply.so 

[  4%] Built
target pcl_io_ply

make: *** [all]
Error 2

<== Failed to process package 'pcl':

Command
'/opt/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/nodelet_topic_tools/env.sh
make -j8 -l8' returned non-zero exit
status 2

Reproduce this error by running:

==> cd /opt/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl
&&
/opt/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/nodelet_topic_tools/env.sh
make -j8 -l8

Command failed, exiting.
```

I have already checked the pcl_find_ros.cmake and it's seems up to date. (h ttps://github.com/ros-gbp/pcl-release/commits/bf43ffc0eebca4042c6765319c4dd211409d7ace/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake)
Any ideas? :\

EDIT:
Command:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated -j1 --install-space /opt/ROS/groovy/

make[2]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/pcl_base.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'pcl': 
  Command '/opt/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/nodelet_topic_tools/env.sh make -j1' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /opt/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl && /opt/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/nodelet_topic_tools/env.sh make -j1

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125191/package-pcl---ubuntu-13.10---installation-ros-groovy-from-source/) by [bapclenet](https://answers.ros.org/users/11526/bapclenet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-31**:
I feel like the actual error message is missing here. Do you get any more information by running ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated -j1 --install-space /opt/ros/groovy/ ?

**Comment by [bapclenet](https://answers.ros.org/users/11526/bapclenet/) on 2014-02-01**:
I edited my post, it's not exactly the same error but quite similar. What do you think?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-01**:
Can you include more of the error output? I don't see anything that actually looks like an error from the compiler. Ideally, everything from the first error message onward is useful.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-11**:
Does "VERBOSE=1 ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated -j1 --install-space /opt/ros/groovy/" output more info? If not, run make clean for pcl first (or remove the pcl build dir) and try again with VERBOSE=1 and -j1

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-02-11**:
Having the same problem here. Any luck with this?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-11**:
Related question: http://answers.ros.org/question/126846/error-installing-ros-groovy-from-source-on-ubuntu-1310/

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-02-11**:
Exactly! Thanks ahendrix!

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-11**:
@TSC, what about that full error log with VERBOSE=1 and -j1?

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-02-16**:
@ahendrix, already added -j1. Please, check related question: http://answers.ros.org/question/126846/error-installing-ros-groovy-from-source-on-ubuntu-1310/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@TSC provided output with VERBOSE=1 and -j1 over at http://answers.ros.org/question/126846/error-installing-ros-groovy-from-source-on-ubuntu-1310/

Might be it is the same issue of Eigen / PCL incompatibility here. I just answered there:

> It seems like you have a Eigen version
> installed that is too new for PCL. It
> seems in 3.2 the sqrt function moved
> from eigen::internal::sqrt to
> eigen::sqrt. See this question:
>
> http://answers.ros.org/question/128916/ros-groovy-compile-fails-at-pcl/
>
> So you could either try to change the
> source of PCL or make sure it is using
> eigen 3.1 to compile.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0